# (Javascript) Microphone and audio from mediastream are out of sync

Tags: javascript, audio, getusermedia, howler.js

I wrote a recorder that records microphone from getUsermedia and audio which is from local using Howler JS.
I created mediastream destination, and
connected each sources (mic, audio) to the destination.
audio seems fine, but microphone is delayed about 2seconds.
I can't figure out the problem.
could you help me guys?

```
var recorder;
const stop = document.getElementsByClassName("stop");
const record = document.getElementsByClassName("record");

let mediaDest = Howler.ctx.createMediaStreamDestination();
Howler.masterGain.connect(mediaDest);
function onRecordingReady(e) {
  // 'e' has 'blob event'
  //var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
  audioBlob = e.data; // e.data has blob.
  //audio.src = URL.createObjectURL(e.data);
}

let audioBlob;
let audioURL = "";

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true }).then(function (stream) {
  let userMic = Howler.ctx.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
  userMic.connect(mediaDest);
  Howler.masterGain.connect(mediaDest);
  recorder = new MediaRecorder(mediaDest.stream);
  recorder.addEventListener("dataavailable", onRecordingReady);
  recorder.addEventListener("stop", function () {
    W3Module.convertWebmToMP3(audioBlob).then((mp3blob) => {
      const downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
      downloadLink.href = URL.createObjectURL(mp3blob);
      downloadLink.setAttribute("download", "audio");
      //downloadLink.click();
      var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
      audio.src = URL.createObjectURL(mp3blob);
      console.log(mp3blob);
    });
  });
});

record[0].addEventListener("click", function () {
  recorder.start();
});

stop[0].addEventListener("click", function () {
  recorder.stop();
});
```

Comment: Sounds like a buffering issue. The mic is obviously buffered for 2 seconds. If you have a possibility to reduce that buffer time, take it. Be aware that, at some point, underruns will occur and that’s gonna be audible.

Comment: @Psi Thank you Psi, i'm now aware of the buffering issue, but i could'n find the way. I will keep trying.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the solution.
I didn't know I could connect MediaStreamAudioSourceNode to GainNode.
If someone is suffering this issue, just connect one Node to another Node rather than connect each node to the destination.

I connected the sourceNode to the GainNode, and connected GainNode to the destination.

=========================
It was not the solution...
GainNode playback in realtime whenever input is present...so, even if i can remove the latency, annoying playback occurs.